# Mapeamento de uma List<long> no LINQ to SQL - Windows Phone 7.1

Tags: entity-framework, linq, windows-phone, orm, linq-to-sql

**Problema**

Estou iniciando uma aplicação para Windows Phone 7.1, e estou implementando a base de dados, só que me deparei com uma situação que não encontrei nenhum exemplo de situação similar para tentar resolver, e também não achei nada que me ajudasse na documentação da Microsoft.

A situação é a seguinte:

Tenho uma `class` similar a essa:

```
public class Setup : INotifyPropertyChanged, INotifyPropertyChanging
{
    private long _id;
    private string _descricao;
    private IList<long> _tempos;

    [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true, DbType = "INT NOT NULL Identity", CanBeNull = false, AutoSync = AutoSync.OnInsert)]
    public virtual long Id
    {
        get { return _id; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _id)
            {
                _id = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Id");
            }
        }
    }

    [Column]
    public virtual string Descricao
    {
        get { return _descricao; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _descricao)
            {
                _descricao = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Nome");
            }
        }
    }

    // como eu faria para mapear corretamente esse campo
    [Column] 
    public virtual IList<long> Tempos
    {
        get
        {
            if (_tempos == null)
                _tempos = new List<long>();
            return _tempos;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != _tempos)
            {
                NotifyPropertyChanging("");
                _tempos = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Tempos");
            }
        }
    }

    // Version column aids update performance.
    [Column(IsVersion = true)]
    private Binary _version;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangingEventHandler PropertyChanging;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanging(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanging != null)
        {
            PropertyChanging(this, new PropertyChangingEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

**Pergunta**

No caso, como eu faria para mapear corretamente o campo `IList<long> Tempos`
, já que não é um campo simples, é uma lista de `long`, ou teria que criar uma `class` (Tempo, por exemplo) e tratar como uma relacionamento 1 x N? Se for assim como seria? Se possível com exemplos.

Comment: Como esse `Tempo` seria preenchido?

Comment: Com tempos em minutos que os setups foram executados.  É tipo um histórico de tempos do setup. Não sei se é a melhor forma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui solucionar o problema (com as dicas do @CiganoMorrisonMendez, mas com algumas modificações importantes em relação as coleções), da seguinte forma:

Criei uma nova entidade para representar os tempos, chamada `Tempo`:

```
[Table]
public class Tempo : INotifyPropertyChanged, INotifyPropertyChanging
{
    private long _id;
    [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true, DbType = "INT NOT NULL Identity", CanBeNull = false, AutoSync = AutoSync.OnInsert)]
    public virtual long Id
    {
        get { return _id; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _id)
            {
                NotifyPropertyChanging("Id");
                _id = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Id");
            }
        }
    }

    private long _minutos;
    [Column]
    public virtual long Minutos
    {
        get { return _minutos; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _minutos)
            {
                NotifyPropertyChanging("Minutos");
                _minutos = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Minutos");
            }
        }
    }

    [Column]
    public long SetupID;
    private EntityRef<Setup> _setup;
    [Association(Storage = "_setup", ThisKey = "SetupID")]
    public virtual Setup Setup
    {
        get { return _setup.Entity; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _setup.Entity)
            {
                NotifyPropertyChanging("Setup");
                _setup.Entity = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Setup");
            }
        }
    }

    // ...
}
```

E modifiquei o mapeamento do atributo `Tempos` da `class` `Setup`, para o seguinte:

```
[Table]
public class Setup : INotifyPropertyChanged, INotifyPropertyChanging
{        
    // ...

    private EntitySet<Tempo> _tempos;
    [Association(Storage = "_tempos", OtherKey = "Id")]
    public virtual EntitySet<Tempo> Tempos
    {
        get
        {
            if (_tempos == null)
                _tempos = new EntitySet<Tempo>();
            return _tempos;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != Tempos)
            {
                NotifyPropertyChanging("Tempos");
                Tempos.Assign(value);
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Tempos");
            }
        }
    }

    // ...
}
```

A problema original era que o `IList<long>`, não eram entidades conhecidas pelo **LINQ to SQL**, então ele não sabia como gerenciar esses atributos, no caso a solução proposta pelo @CiganoMorrisonMendez, era de criar uma entidade para representar o `Tempo` (No caso a tabela que iria guardar os tempos do `Setup`), e representa-lo como uma `ICollection<Tempo>` no `Setup`, no caso do `ICollection`, também acabou não sendo reconhecido pelo **LINQ to SQL**, que me lançou a seguinte `Exception` ao tentar criar a base de dados: `Unable to determine SQL type for 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection'1`, então pesquisando cheguei a [seguinte documentação "obscura" da Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb386950(v=vs.100).aspx), que salvou meu dia. Onde explica e demonstra como representar/mapear relações de cardinalidade no **LINQ to SQL** onde:

- **EntitySet:** Que é utilizado como objeto/lista para representa relações de cardinalidade (`1 X N` e `N X N`);
- **EntityRef:** Que é utilizado como objeto para representar associação simples entre duas entidades;

Answer (score 1):

#### No caso, como eu faria para mapear corretamente o campo `IList<long> Tempos` , já que não é um campo simples, é uma lista de long, ou teria que criar uma class (`Tempo`, por exemplo) e tratar como uma relacionamento 1 x N?

Exatamente.

Qualquer lista ou estrutura de dados que sugira cardinalidade N precisa ser declarada como outra entidade, relacionada com a entidade em questão.

#### E como eu trataria essa cardinalidade? Qual a anotação eu utilizaria?

Mais ou menos assim:

```cs
public class Entidade
{
    [Key]
    public int EntidadeId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Tempo> Tempos { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: E como eu trataria essa cardinalidade? Qual a anotação eu utilizaria?

Comment: Vou colocar na resposta.

Comment: Não é necessário nenhuma anotação sobre a propriedade `public virtual ICollection<Tempo> Tempos { get; set; }`? O ORM (não sei qual ORM realmente é, acredito que seja [LINQ to SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh202860(v=vs.105).aspx)) já vai entender isso, se logicamente a classe `Tempo` estiver devidamente mapeada?

Comment: @Fernando Exatamente. O Entity Framework é bem espertinho.

Comment: Mas um questionamento, é que estou com algumas duvidas sobre este ORM e preciso entende-lo um pouco melhor, para trabalhar com o mesmo. Então na classe `Tempo` eu tenho que criar uma referência a `Setup` no meu caso, ou esse relacionamento ele já abstrai e mantem somente a relação na base de dados? Estou perguntando isso pois é uma relação `1 X N`, então na base de dados `N` deve ter uma referencia a `1`, o que indicará a qual `1` `N` pertence, e quais `N`s pertencem a `1`. Ficou entendível?

Comment: Sim, você tem que criar a propriedade inversa para `Setup` em `Tempo`, mais ou menos assim: `public virtual Setup Setup { get; set; }`, e também a propriedade que vai representar a chave: `public int SetupId { get; set; }`

Comment: Ok, Cigano, vou analisar essa abordagem em meu projeto(a noite), e verificar se atende as necessidades (aparentemente, compilou mentalmente, hehe). E me desculpe pela quantidade de indagações sobre o assunto, é que estava com muitas duvidas.

Comment: @Fernando Tranquilo. Qualquer coisa grita, ou me chama no chat.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discuss&#227;o no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17971/discussion-between-fernando-and-cigano-morrison-mendez).